# Annotations with custom image on Mapkit with Drag and Drop animation

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mapkit

I am using Swift on iOS 8.x. I have a few annotations on my map(kit) with a custom image. If I drag and drop them around I would like to have the same animation as apple has with the default pins.

All I've found here on Stackoverflow is pretty old (around 4 years)..

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: what kind of animation.Can you elaborate more

Comment: The original pins provide an animate where the pins will be lifted up on drag and "will be thrown down" on drop.